# how to redirect to other page after fb login

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

i have created fb login functionality to my project when user click on login with facebook,it redirect user to facebook and after successful it return back to that login page but i want to redirect it to other page.
i tried a following but it not's work

```
function index(){   
            $redirect='http://login.dev';       
            echo $user = $this->facebook->getUser();                                    
            echo $token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();                                    
    if(!$user){                    
        $user=null;
                    // Generate a login url
        $data['url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$redirect,'scope'=>'email')); 
        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    }else{
        // Get user's data and print it
        $user = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
        print_r($user)
        $this->load->view('userProfile',$user);                        
    }              
}
```

so my question is that how to redirect it to other page if successfully login.

Comment: *"i have created fb login when user click on login with facebook,it redirect user to facebook and after successful it return back to that login page."* - That should be phrased like: *"i have created fb login when user click on login with facebook, it **should** redirect user to facebook and after successful it **should** return back to that login page."*

Comment: FB has restriction for redirection urls , its matching the domain to the approved domains inside the FB application settings. If your redirct domain is not listed you wont have success ..

Comment: you shouldn't post your fb token here

Comment: ok..
so can help me to solve this issue
i got the token from fb so its mean its successful login?

Comment: why would you want to redirect to another domain? that does not make any sense.

Comment: no i want to redirect to other page not domain sir..@luschn

Comment: well, your login process seems to be broken, not the redirection. there are hundreds of stackoverflow threads about the "userid=0" problem.

Comment: btw, i suggest using the javascript sdk for login, it´s a lot easier to handle. not sure why so many people use the php sdk for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REplace your Else part

```
else{
   // Get user's data and print it
   $user = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
   return redirect('/login/form/', 'refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else{
        // Get user's data and print it
        $user = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
        //print_r($user)

    //$this->load->view('userProfile',$user);                        
     header('Location: your-page-path-after-login.php');
    }
```

I think you are asking for this use **header('Location: your-page-path-after-login.php');** in else part of your code.

Comment: but it can't  go to else part after login

Comment: then which part of code it comes after successful login?

Comment: else part will come but it does not goes to else part that's my problem
getUser() return 0 so it goes to if part

Comment: then change your question please, It means your facebook login is not working.

Comment: no sir its working, it returns a token but getUSer() return 0.